# TypeScript recursively convert object keys from PascalCase to camelCase format

Tags: typescript

I need to create a function to modify keys of object from PascalCase to camelCase format. Ie

```
const input = {
    FirstName: 'John',
    LastName: 'Smith'
};

const expectedOutput = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
};

// function looks as follows
function pascalToCamelCase<T>(input: T): CamelCaseKeys<T> {
    if (typeof input !== 'object' || input === null) {
        return input;
    }

    // do conversion....
    return output;
}
```

But I don't know how to modify keys accordingly via CamelCaseKeys

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I learned something today! We can use the new typescript 4.1 template string literal features and utility methods to achieve this in a typesafe way.

`Capitalize<T>` will capitalise a string.

`Uncapitalize<T>` will uncapitalise a string (what you're after).

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html) on these.

From these two we can build a helper type `UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T>`:

```js
type UncapitalizeKeys<T extends object> = Uncapitalize<keyof T & string>;

type UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T extends object> = {
  [key in UncapitalizeKeys<T>]: Capitalize<key> extends keyof T ? T[Capitalize<key>] : never;
}
```

Notes:

- `Uncapitalize<keyof T & string>` - we intersect with string to only get the keys of T which are strings, as we can't capitalise numbers or symbols
- We have to uncapitalise the keys in `[key in UncapitalizeKeys<T>]` - and then re-capitalise them to actually pull the proper value out of T with `T[Capitalize<key>]`. The conditional part `Capitalize<key> extends keyof T`  is just checking if the capitalised, uncapitalised key still is assignable to `keyof T`, as TS isn't able to maintain this relationship (...yet?).

We can then pull a couple of parts out of @spender's answer - replacing the runtime type checking as TS should be able to assert these (assuming these objects aren't coming from IO:

```
type UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T extends object> = {
  [key in UncapitalizeKeys<T>]: Capitalize<key> extends keyof T ? T[Capitalize<key>] : never;
}

type UncapitalizeKeys<T extends object> = Uncapitalize<keyof T & string>;


export const lowerCaseKeys = <T extends object>(obj: T): UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T> => {
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);
    const mappedEntries = entries.map(
        ([k, v]) => [
            `${k.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase()}${k.substr(1)}`,
            lowerCaseKeys(v)]
    );

    return Object.fromEntries(mappedEntries) as UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T>;
};
```

We now get the output we're after:

[image]

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgYwIZgJbCQG1QLwgeQCMArCBYAaQhAGcAeAFSggA9gI4ATGqAexLLAAfFAC8UAN4AoKFADaAa2pRUcWIhTosuCFVqMhAXQBcUAMKaM2PHSUgRrdlx53eAMyhMA-J7kW0Vjq21EZQpnAQAG4QAE4A3FIAvlJSoJDqyAHaeHr0TI4c3HwC5CLi8Jla1hDBIO6eUABkUDTAMaoA5kIJKaxgvDHAUAi8cK1QmLwA7rEWNLrUPOKMzGyFPPykpQAUm6YMAJSmFZbZBCWUiwZiItKysiNjQxxtqBBLUERbwAB0L%203vXYkA4Je7DUbjAC2KEgnAAonBXu8xMxEQCaD9oWBtjIwfdtooADRQSKGA43eS4vF4gAGABIJAofjQAK6EVoxbYABmJAEYDj9gLwADLTWZIebbA6JBlM1nstrbfmJGmEqnU%206TGYxOYLWjbSIHQzqkEpMExCDAFkxNRfQQ-NwxXiQhFImjbLGw13o8kSjKnap28i5AwJRI9R7jFgorXi%20a5bYSKAAMV4vFMAHIkIQEBniQAhJAxTOcCBuDOJU0sH6EIs9IA)

Comment: Unfortunately I have TS 3.2. So I need some 'older' approach

Comment: Not possible in that case sadly

Comment: methodologySaga.ts:59 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 3):

I will put more modern answer here just for visibility.
Though the implementation in the other answers is correct, I think this type is more elegant. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgYwIZgJbCQG1QLwgeQCMArCBYAaQhAGcAeAFQD4oBeKAbwCgooBtANbUoqOFCEgA9gDMoDKEhqxEKdFlwQ6EqADIoNYACdRAcyYBdAFxzB1c1AgAPYBDgATJUVLkoAfmXIaBjYeF5klNT0DLYg5izW0RLmXAC%20XFygkFBebJw8vFBUIACM1nAArgC2hBCGANz5vBIATNYGxnAmDQVQkmDAqJJwWABiqBCYbr7WhJKSmBBIcN0FhmTlhjSoAG4Q1tw9PUUAzNYAFACUbCzbkqhujVBpaRng0AwQBrnwgWohBCRwkV6F4mOkEEMvi4DAlPsBcgcChJSlBjgAaR4tawAIha2IxPTWCA2W12%200ePQkpygl2unDSPWeQA)

```
type UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T> = {
  [key in keyof T as Uncapitalize<key & string>]: T[key] extends Object ? UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T[key]> : T[key]
}
```

Works since 4.1

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please add playground link as well

Comment: @Timothy sure. I also updated it to be recursive over fields

Comment: Very neat solution. I love it mate

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recursive solution that I've used to good effect:

```
export const lowerCaseKeys = (obj: any): any => {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
        return obj;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
        return obj.map(lowerCaseKeys);
    }
    if (obj === null) {
        return null;
    }
    const entries = Object.entries(obj);
    const mappedEntries = entries.map(
        ([k, v]) => [
            `${k.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase()}${k.substr(1)}`,
            lowerCaseKeys(v)] as const
    );
    return Object.fromEntries(mappedEntries);
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBANiA7gUwE4GECGFkGlkCeEMAvDABQgBGAVgFwyZgECUDTBpAfDAN4BQMITACWAMwpQCAB2QgJ1GjACEJMgHJFyYFHUs+g4UdTIoAV1RgYigNyGhAX3uiJ5AIKpUmAgDoREDy8CSloWfQEjY1MLK0UfAFtMaXIEFAxsPEIIFjsjJyNxCkVSNRgwMzg4cOco80syirhc4XzhUEhYZDAoVBFkYjIAeVptKB8unr6IEJoc53boGETpWQATAFFu3v7SGAntiASk8hrhcgBtAGsAGhgANwBdfRIec4ADABJeS58IMypoKhyAAGW4ARhYPigIAAMkg0FgcOQWA4vj8-gCeuQIQ43rdUgiMvgiOQ7iwHoxiAsoM45rUYjBhjRRj4xKgQPFNpN+uRlmsuQc5g47PxqaIwNIzLAyBFhAAxESoaAAOUw8WQDHUACkQAALMDqa7OGHYKCq9WagDK8REUF16n4wv4ovAEBAcGQPgQAHMUvD0jhidMRBKpWFnWLQPFpB6AB4ASVD0oMRkGvW9iclUAYssiMAVSrNao1MG1eoNRrzQhNKuLVptdodeUrwkwnm8malDHOpyEuarQjTIgzSZzvYH+cVtYtpZ1+sN44HNaLM-U1tt9sXLRbE5ggQ7o5gPd3ef7J8iBenJbL85358iy-N1-Xja3eYctzP96El5X17nFZvhOj51qWL6bt+jhAQ844fimJ4eMOnbZvB36-k+moAQukEwCBq7gU2J4fkBlocsgyqNAw5SVHeA5uBR8RUGgDAAOywc4MFOC6kDup6Pp+mkiKZCSUYxsgCZJuGQA)

Comment: turns out you can actually type this now with TS 4.1 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html

Comment: thank for that... this part I have, I don't have TypeScript part... The most important part I need implement is: (obj: any): any

Comment: check my answer for the TS part @Timothy

Answer (score 0):

This particular form works better with intellisense, *and* handles arrays

```js
export type UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T> = T extends Array<infer U>
  ? Array<UncapitalizeObjectKeys<U>>
  : T extends object
  ? {
      [K in keyof T as Uncapitalize<string & K>]: UncapitalizeObjectKeys<T[K]>
    }
  : T

type Movie = {
  Title: string
  Year: number
}

type BibliographyPascalCase = {
  DirectorName: string
  Movies: Movie[]
}

type BibliographyCamelCase = UncapitalizeObjectKeys<BibliographyPascalCase>

/*
type BibliographyCamelCase = {
  directoName: string
  movies: {
    title: string
    year: number 
  }[]
*/
```