# Typescript: Allow only uppercase keys in object

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to contruct a type that will allow any kind of keys for object as long as they are UPPERCASE?

I want this to pass:

```js
const example: OnlyUppercaseKeys = {
  TEST: 'any string',
  TEST_ME: 'any string'
};
```

and I want this to fail:

```js
const example: OnlyUppercaseKeys = {
  Test: 'any string',
  'test_me': 'any string'
};
```

I know there are [string manipulation types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#intrinsic-string-manipulation-types). I can even use them to construct a type that will convert any keys to uppercase, but I don't know how to write type with a test that would check it in `Record<???, string>`

Comment: Does this answer help https://stackoverflow.com/a/65020179/4155700 ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That's why I wrote that I know how to use string manipulation types to convert but not to test.

Answer (score 4):

```js
const example: Record<Capitalize<string>, unknown> = {
    TEST: 'any string',
    TEST_ME: 'any string',
    a: 'a'
}; // don't work
```

It is possible to do it with standalone type if you know all of your keys upfront.

```js
type AllowedKeys = 'a' | 'b'

const example2: Record<Uppercase<AllowedKeys>, unknown> = {
    A: 'a',
    B: 'b'
}
```

In order to do this, you should use an extra function.

```js
const uppercaseed = <
    Keys extends string,
    Obj extends Record<Keys, unknown>
>(obj: Obj & Record<Uppercase<keyof Obj & string>, unknown>) => obj

uppercaseed({ AA: 1 }) // ok
uppercaseed({ Aa: 1 }) // error
uppercaseed({ aa: 1 }) // error
```

Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68963491/define-a-typescript-type-that-takes-a-lowercase-word/68963571#68963571). It almost the same, you just need to replace `Lowercase` with `Upercase`

Comment: Interesting take. This method function does static type checking, but it's a little unhandy. Unfortunately I don't know all keys. The object will be expanded with more keys in the future. However, you are right that the question you linked is almost the same think I asked.

Comment: If you don\t know all keys - unfortunatelly you should use extra function